Why doesn't the method to calculate height for width with font calculate height correctly?
This is my method:
extension String {
    func height(with font: UIFont, forWidth width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        label.setDynamicFont(font)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.text = self
        label.sizeToFit()
        return label.frame.height
    }
}

extension UIView {
    func setDynamicFont(_ font: UIFont) {
        enableDynamicFont()
        if let label = self as? UILabel {
            label.font = font.scaled
        }
    }

    func enableDynamicFont() {
        if let adjustable = self as? UIContentSizeCategoryAdjusting {
            adjustable.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
        }
        maximumContentSizeCategory = .extraExtraExtraLarge
    }
}

extension UIFont {
    static var poppinsRegular: UIFont {
        UIFont(name: "Poppins-Regular", size: 16)!
    }

    var scaled: UIFont {
        UIFontMetrics.default.scaledFont(for: self)
    }
}

How do I use it?
contentTextView.snp.updateConstraints { maker in
    maker.height.equalTo(height(for: message.attributedText.string))
}

How do I define height for my label?
private func height(for text: String) -> CGFloat {
    let font = UIFont.poppinsRegular.withSize(16)
    print("::: text: \(text)")
    print("::: width: \(contentTextView.frame.width)")
    print("::: height: \(text.height(with: font, forWidth: contentTextView.frame.width))")
    return text.height(with: font, forWidth: contentTextView.frame.width)
}

The output on console is the following:

::: text: abcsruweź udział w ankiecie, liczy się każdy głos, twoja opinia ma dla nas bardzo duże znaczenie, cenimy Twoją opinię, podziel sie z nami tym co myslisz Dlugga nazwa ankiety, sie zastanawiam czy ma wplyw na ucinanie linkow weź udział w ankiecie, liczy się każdy głos, twoja opinia ma dla nas bardzo duże znaczenie, cenimy Twoją opinię, podziel sie z nami tym co myslisz Dlugga nazwa ankiety, sie zastanawiam czy ma wplyw na ucinanie linkow
::: width: 304.0
::: height: 291.3333333333333

and the result in app:

As you can see it is not fully displayed. Why?
PS
contentTextView is UILabel. Not best name, but type is UILabel.

Why do you want to calculate height and set a height constraint at all? Auto layout eliminates the need to do that. All of this (including the relatively expensive String extension to create a label to get the height and then discard that UILabel) seems unnecessary. We generally let the auto layout system to do all of this for us. And, in edge cases, we will setContentHuggingPriority and setContentCompressionResistancePriority as appropriate, so the label hugs the content and isn’t compressed.

Which problem are you trying to solve? Because as Rob said auto-layout method is quite reliable, and needs no such custom low level handling in most cases...

Ok, I forgot to mention that I use MessageKit library for custom cells in my chat views. Does it support autolayout too?
